# SQL Combining tables displaying Nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql

So my question is this.

I would like to Pull data from table 1.
Then after pulling that data pull data from table 2 but also show the nulls.

So right now I have this

```
Select a.*, b.description from table 1 a
LEFT JOIN table 2 on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.description = "hello"
```

So I would like for it to Always show the information from table and only show the information from table 2 if the where clause is hit

So look something like

```
Table 1      Table 2
ID1          NULL
ID2          NULL
ID3          hello
ID4          NULL
```

But all I get back of course is

```
Table 1     Table 2
ID3         hello
```

I'm trying to use LINQ to do it but I'm trying to figure it out on SQL first because I know that more.

I don't know if this made any sense but thanks!

Comment: What is your desired output ? can you share the o/p sample

Comment: `"hello"` is a column name, did you mean the string constant `'hello'`?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your `where` clause. By meaning of left join all the ids that will be there in table1 with ids matching between table1 & table2 will be the o/p

```
    Select a.*, b.description from table 1 a
    LEFT JOIN table 2 on a.id = b.id and 
      b.description="hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use INNER JOIN for this purpose

```
Select a.*, b.description from table 1 a
INNER JOIN table 2 on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.description = "hello"
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/1118978) for detailed explaination

Comment: See I thought this too but it still only shows the ones with that discription.

Comment: `"hello"` should be `'hello'`

Answer (score 0):

Allow `null` in `where`

```
SELECT a.*, b.description 
FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.description IS NULL OR b.description = 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add or b.description is null to the WHERE clause:

```
Select a.*, b.description 
from table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b 
on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.description = "hello" or b.description is null
```